# Distribute feature importance to the components of the features in a PCA regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, pca, supervised-learning, importance

I read some interesting speculation over on the Data Science Stack. The setup is that there are multiple correlated features in a regression problem, and the goal is to determine feature importance.

The speculative idea was to calculate principal components of the features, regress on the principal components, calculate feature importance for those principal components, and then distribute the feature importance on the principal components to the original features.

While I envision issues with this, I had never thought of or considered such an idea. Is this approach viable? What issues might there be?

**EDIT**

I’m open to interpretations, though I think distributing the feature importance would mean to multiply the feature importance by the proportional weight of each feature in the principal component, then add up over all principal components used in the regression.

Comment: What does "*distribute the feature importance on the principal components to the original features*" mean mathematically?

Comment: I’m open to interpretations, though I think it would mean to multiply the feature importance by the proportional weight of each feature in the principal component. @Galen